# Searching Riemann zeta zeros in nuclear data files.

Tags: riemann-zeta

Is this match between some of the truncated Riemann zeta zeros and numbers in nuclear calculation data only a coincidence?

I calculated these numbers from the Riemann zeta zeros and looked them up in Google:

> 1.55974324 found at https://www-nds.iaea.org/point2004/k300/ZA026054
>   1.34835538 found at https://www-nds.iaea.org/point2009/100eV/ZA020042
>   1.28559070 not found at iaea
>   1.22938585 not found at iaea
>   1.21018709 found at https://www-nds.iaea.org/point2004/1KEV/ZA096242
>   1.18195215 not found at iaea
>   1.16596938 found at https://www-nds.iaea.org/point2009/K2100/ZA032074
>   1.15605984 found at https://www-nds.iaea.org/point2009/1keV/ZA032076
>   1.13983743 not found at iaea
>   1.13454842 not found at iaea
>   1.12593870 not found at iaea
>   1.11774439 not found at iaea
>   1.11167947 not found at iaea
>   1.10881056 not found at iaea
>   1.10130661 not found at iaea

The numbers are of the form:

$$\exp \left(\frac{1}{\frac{\Im(\rho _n)}{2 \pi }}\right)$$

where $n=1$ to $15$

I guess this question will get down voted, and I will delete it when that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled $50$ numbers of this form, with a $1$ before the decimal point and $8$ manually randomised digits after the decimal point. Of these, $2$ were found in https://www-nds.iaea.org/point2004. Thus the probability of such a number being found can be estimated to be roughly $\frac1{25}$. Of the $15$ numbers you searched for, you found $2$ in this directory. The probability for this to happen is estimated at $\binom{15}224^{13}/25^{15}\approx10\%$, so this is not a remarkable event.

I was going to repeat the experiment with the entire site, https://www-nds.iaea.org, but when the very first two numbers I tried were hits, I figured that this is a waste of time and I don't understand why you didn't try this yourself, since I usually find your other contributions to the site quite interesting.

Comment: Yes of course, I should have tried more random numbers. I did try maybe 5 random numbers yesterday and found one match. I stayed up late last night, and I woke up tired today when I asked the question.